# Calculating with conditions over a mask on numpy without loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array x

```
x = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]])
```

and I have a mask m

```
m = np.array([[True, False, True], [False, True, False]])
```

I would like to calculate with conditions as follows:

```
y = 10*x[i, j] if m[i, j] == True else 2*x[i,j]
```

The expected output should be

```
100, 40, 300
80, 500, 120
```

May I have your suggestions how to do it without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> np.where(m, 10*x, 2*x)
array([[100,  40, 300],
       [ 80, 500, 120]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x[m] *= 10
x[~m] *= 2
print(x)
```

Output:

```
array([[100,  40, 300],
       [ 80, 500, 120]])
```

Comment: For readers, the tilde computes the inverse of the mask. All true values become false, and false values become true.